# func = elem [1..10] works in GHCi but doesn't compile

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghci

In GHCi running this command

`func = elem [1..10]`

Works just fine and gives me a partial function back. I'm curious as to why it works? When I try compiling this code it gives me an error. For example this does not work work with other functions. Map gives me an error in GHCi and when I compile it.

`func = map [1..10]`

Curious what is special about GHCi and the function elem.

I know that I can write it as:

`` func = (`elem` [1..10]) ``

`` func = (`map` [1..10]) ``

And it works, but why does the other way work for elem.

Comment: What error do you get when you try compiling it?

Comment: ``elem [1..10]`` and ``(`elem` [1..10])`` are very different things! You seem to be operating under the misconception that they're equivalent. ``elem [1..10]`` is actually equivalent to ``([1..10] `elem`)``.

Comment: If you want help understanding why a thing doesn't work, you have to at minimum 1. show us the thing that doesn't work (for example, by pasting the exact code you try to compile) and 2. describe what "doesn't work" means (for example, by pasting the exact error you get).

Comment: Check the type of `elem`. It's first argument is a type and second is a foldable that contains that type. In your case the first argument's type is `[a]` and what it expexts as a second argument could be any foldable data structure that contains `[a]`s such as `[[a]]` for instance. What confuses you is that the initial argument `[a]` is also foldable hence it can also be used as a second argument i.e `\`elem\` [a]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elem [1..10]` is a perfectly sensible term. Example:

```
Prelude> elem [1..10] [[0..9], [1..10]]
True
Prelude> elem [1..10] [[0..8], [1..7]]
False
```

Perhaps more commonly, this would be written

```
Prelude> [1..10] `elem` [[0..9], [1..10]]
True
Prelude> [1..10] `elem` [[0..8], [1..7]]
False
```

but that's just a different syntactic version of the same thing.

That means also it *can* be compiled, you just need to give it an appropriate signature (or have GHC infer one for you). For example,

```
f :: [[Int]] -> Bool
f = elem [1..10]
```

...it's the function that tells you whether a list of number-lists contains the list `[1..10]`. I.e. like in any other use of `elem`, it tells you whether some list contains an element. The fact that this element happens to be itself a list is irrelevant.

On the other hand `map [1..10]` is just wrong, because the first argument to `map` must be a *function*. And lists, while they can be list-elements, can never be functions<sup>†</sup>.

It's quite a different story with the operator-sections `` (`elem`[1..10]) `` and `` (`map`[1..10]) ``. In those examples, `[1..10]` is actually the *second* argument. The section leaves out the left/first argument. So in this case what we're talking about is like

```
Prelude> 3 `elem` [1..10]
True
Prelude> 19 `elem` [1..10]
False
```

...and that also works with

```
Prelude> negate `map` [1..10]
[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10]
```

though that would be more commonly written `map negate [1..10]` or `negate<$>[1..10]`.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>In a sense that's simultaneously pedantic and anarchic, lists *can* actually be functions: with the [`-XOverloadedLists`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-OverloadedLists) extension, you could write a class-instance that would allow you to define functions using list-syntax. I don't see how that could possibly make any sense, but maybe it's good to be aware of this theoretical possibility. In particular, with that extension enabled, `map [1..10]` confusingly *does* compile, and you merely get a confusing error involving `Could not deduce` ... `The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous` gibberish elsewhere.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! Makes much more sense now!